# В Laravel коде неизвестные функции?

Tags: laravel

В Laravel коде есть неизвестные функции например (kebab_case, camel_case)
в документации [laravel 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers)  про них ничего ни нашел.

Можно ли использовать эти функции ?

Где можно найти полный список helper функций Laravel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это хелперы из предыдущих версий. [В описании по обновлению](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#string-and-array-helpers) указано, что эти хелперы устарели и были вынесены в отдельный [репозиторий](https://github.com/laravel/helpers). Поэтому, если нужны хелперы - добавь зависимость в `composer.json` или используй методы классов `Illuminate\Support\Arr` и `Illuminate\Support\Str` напрямую